# Where is the executable file built by Cordova Windows or OSX

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, cordova, build

I am trying to build a Windows application with Cordova and Visual Studio Community 2017. Where can I find executable file after building the app? All I see in

```
C:\Users\Intel\source\repos\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bin\Windows-x64\Release
```

are:

- /AppxManifest.xml
- /BlankCordovaApp1.build.appxrecipe
- /resources.pri
- /ilc/

Isn't there supposed to be an .exe file for us to launch the application?

I would also like to ask the same question about Cordova OSX. Where can I find the executable file launching the Mac application after building it on XCode?

Answer (score 0):

It is not exe file it is an APPX file. You have to configure with your Windows developer id and other credentials needed.
I don't think you are able to run it with windows emulator or the local windows machine.

Windows and Windows Phone
When building for Windows/Windows Phone 8.1 and 10, Cordova generates a Windows Runtime app (APPX). When building for Windows Phone 8, it generates a Silverlight (XAP) WebView app. These apps are launched in the same way as a native Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8 project in Visual Studio. For more information, see Run Your Apache Cordova App on Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/run-your-app/run-app-windows?view=toolsforcordova-2017